# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal view ID in JSF

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat

when i run jsf project in to tomcat it gives me error like below..

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal view ID .jsp/Welcome.jsp.  The ID must begin with /
    com.sun.faces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.getActionURL(ViewHandlerImpl.java:629)
    com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.getActionURL(FaceletViewHandler.java:781)
    com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.handleFaceletNotFound(FaceletViewHandler.java:686)
    com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.renderView(FaceletViewHandler.java:637)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:106)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.phase(LifecycleImpl.java:251)
    com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:144)
    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:245)
```

**Faces-config.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<faces-config xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_1_2.xsd"
    version="1.2">

    <application>
        <view-handler>com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler</view-handler>
    </application></faces-config>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    version="2.5"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
        <param-value>.jsp</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

**index.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%
String path = request.getContextPath();
String basePath = request.getScheme()+"://"+request.getServerName()+":"+request.getServerPort()+path+"/";
%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <base href="<%=basePath%>">
        <title>Index</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        This is my Index page.
        <a href="jsp/Welcome.jsf"> <<< here</a>
        <br>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Welcome.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f" %>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Welcome</title>
</head>
<body>
    <f:view>
        Welcome Page. <br>
    </f:view>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're telling JSF to use Facelets as view technology, but yet you're *actually* using JSPs as views. This is not going to work. Facelets is the successor of JSP and you should choose to use the one or the other.

Assuming that you just want to use JSPs, then you should **remove** the `<view-handler>` from the `faces-config.xml`, also **remove** `javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX` param from `web.xml` and preferably also **remove** the `ConfigureListener` declaration from `web.xml`.

Or if you *actually* want to use Facelets (recommendable!), then you'll need to configure Facelets and rewrite your JSPs to XHTMLs as per this [Facelets developer guide](http://facelets.java.net/nonav/docs/dev/docbook.html).